# Como ajustar a impressão de um Html em duas colunas?

Tags: php, html, css, impressão

Caros colegas,

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em PHP com o zend Framework2. Neste programa tenho gerar um PDF estilizado contendo o cabeçalho, corpo e rodapé (estou usando o DOMPDF).
A estrutura básica das três div's já estão prontas e funcionando, com os espaçamentos necessários de impressão e repetições do cabeçalho e rodapé, sempre que ocorre uma quebras de página.

Agora preciso trabalhar especificamente na estilização do corpo. 
Tenho um único FOREACH para fazer a busca dos dados e preciso fazer com que este comando preencha o corpo em duas colunas na vertical, iniciando da esquerda para a direita. Somente após o preenchimento das duas colunas é que a quebra de página deve ocorrer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../public/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <meta charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Layout de Impressão</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            margin: 120px 50px 80px 50px;
        }

        #topo {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 110px;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: -75px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #corpo {
            width: 700px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            top: 75px;
        }

        #rodape {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            border-top: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .rodape .page:after {
            content: counter(page);
        }

        .bloco_pai {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .bloco_filho_centralizado {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 50%;
        }

        .bloco_filho_direita {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .bloco_filho_esquerda {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topo" class="text-center">
    <div class="bloco_filho_esquerda">
        <img src="../../../../../public/assets/img/logo/logo-menu2.png" width="160" height="60"/>
    </div>
    <div class="bloco_filho_direita">
        <img src="../../../../../public/assets/img/logo/logo-menu.png" width="160" height="60"/>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="rodape">
    <div class="page" align="right"><span>Arquivo gerado em: </span>
        <?php
        $data = date("d/m/Y H:i");
        #xd($data);
        echo $data;
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="corpo">
    <?php
    $nrQuestoes = count($arQuestoesProva);
    if ($nrQuestoes == 0) { ?>
        <div style="text-align: left" class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                echo "<h2> Nao existem questoes adicionadas a esta avaliação</h2>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo "<h2 style='text-align: center'> Questoes da Prova </h2>";
        ?>
        <div style="text-align: left" class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                $questaoService = new \Questao\Service\QuestaoService();
                $alternativaquestaoService = new \AlternativaQuestao\Service\AlternativaQuestaoService();
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($arQuestoesProva as $key => $item) {
                    $arQuestao = $questaoService->buscar($item['id_questao'])->toArray();
                    echo "<h4>" . $i++ . " - " . $arQuestao['nm_titulo_questao'] . "</h4>";
                    echo "<p>" . $arQuestao['tx_enunciado'] . "</p>";
                    $arAlternativaQuestao = $alternativaquestaoService->fetchAllById(['id_questao' => $item['id_questao']]);
                    $j = 'a';
                    foreach ($arAlternativaQuestao as $key => $alternativa) {
                        echo "<p>" . $j++ . ") " . $alternativa['tx_alternativa_questao'] . "</p>";
                    }
                    echo "<br/>";
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?= $dadosProva->getDsProva() ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Eu creio que você consiga fazer essa divisão de colunas para impressão com o seguinte Media Query de CSS:

```
@media print {
    .conteudo {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

Com essa Media Query, o efeito de duas colunas irá aparecer somente na impressão (Pode ver o efeito com o ctrl + p).

Selecione a div pai de todo o conteúdo que você deseja em 2 colunas. (No caso acho que seria essa de classe: conteudo)

Comment: Para ver versão de impressão e poder inspecionar o código e tal, dá para abrir no console do chrome, apertar "esc", aba "rendering", marcar o "emulate CSS media" e selecionar "print"

Comment: @LuizRossi Boa. Não sabia dessa. Geralmente só dava um Ctrl + P mesmo que já aparecia de forma impressa.

Comment: @LeonFreire não é muito bem isso que preciso. O preenchimento em duas colunas devem ocorrer somente no corpo. Eu editei a pergunta e o código para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: @Eduardoferreira Basta você aplicar o CSS que eu te passei apenas para o corpo. Eu usei no conteúdo porque me parecia a parte do corpo da sua página.

Comment: @LeonFreire infelizmente não está dando certo. quando peço para imprimir o dompdf não está reconhecendo a divisão das colunas. mas obrigado

Comment: @Eduardoferreira Você tentou ao menos trocar o `.conteudo` que eu usei por `#corpo`?

Comment: @LeonFreire sim. Em tela, o código que você me passou está funcionando perfeitamente. Acho que o problema está mesmo no DOMPDF, que não está reconhecendo este CSS, quando é solicitado uma impressão.